# Files not being sorted correctly

Tags: java, list, file

I am aware that my title is kind of misleading, but I wasn't really sure how to put it.

Basically I have a folder with images with the names: 0.png up to 100.png. When I try to load them in with the following method:

```
 public static void buildImageList() {
    Main.log("Building list of image files...");
    File[] files = new File(Constants.getImageLocation()).listFiles();
    int id = 0;
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!file.getName().contains(".png") && !file.getName().contains(".jpg") && !file.getName().contains(".jpeg") && !file.getName().contains(".PNG")) {
            continue;
        }
        imageFiles.add(new FileImage(id, fileToByteArray(file)));
        id++;
    }
    Main.log("Found " + imageFiles.size() + " images in the folder!");
}
```

I get the files not in an ordered sequence: 0.png, 1.png, 10.png, 11.png and so on.

What would I need to change so that I get 0.png, 1.png, 2.png, 3.png?

Comment: Thats because file names are `String` type

Comment: You're getting the natural order of the strings. To get something different you'd have to read all of the file names into a list and the sort it using a Comparator which takes the prefix of the file name and compares it numerically to the others.

Comment: How do you know the order of the files?  Your code snippet only prints the country.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to use:

```
Arrays.sort(files);
```

java.io.File implements Comparable interface, comparing the path names lexicographically. The ordering actually depends on operating system. If you require any custom ordering logic, you may provide custom comparator to Arrays#sort() method:

```
Arrays.sort(files, new CustomFileNameOrderingComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your guidance, I have fixed it using the following code:

```
 Arrays.sort(files, (o1, o2) -> {
        final int id1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.getName().substring(0, o1.getName().indexOf(".")));
        final int id2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.getName().substring(0, o2.getName().indexOf(".")));
        final int result = Integer.compare(id1, id2);
        return result != 0 ? result : (id1 - id2);
    });
```